# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am in the learning phase in the automation.
In my first program, when I am trying to run it, getting below error.

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60 (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875}) on port 57583
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
> ChromeDriver was started successfully.
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
> Current browser version is 102.0.5005.63 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> Build info: version: '4.2.0', revision: '86eb611648'

It will be a great help if anybody help me in this to resolve.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So first thing you should do is update your google chorme.

Click on the 3 dots > help > about google chrome > and check if it is already up to date.

After updating, search for webdrive for google chrome.

Download the version that is the same as yours, for example.
Mine is 103. Then download driver 103.

When you've downloaded the driver, unzip it and insert it into your drivers folder on your user's C:.
Example:
C:\Users\lucas\driver

After putting it in, try to run your program again.

Note * I found this out by going to my system variables and accessing the Paths that were in there.
You can probably find and check beforehand. If there is something in one of your paths like this:
C:\Users\lucas\driver
and paste exactly in that path. It will work.

Comment: If you can, after putting the correct driver. Insert this dependency in your maven. It makes it so that whenever there is a new update, it does the same automatically.

<!--
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactld>webdrivermanager</artifactld>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
  </dependency>